# Text remains in terminal after closing it and reopening

Tags: command-line

I am fairly new to Linux (Ubuntu) and I recently bought a machine pre-loaded. I was practicing learning commands like creating, saving and moving files. Everything was fine for a few days but today when I opened the terminal, the text from the last file that I saved still remains in the terminal and it's on the line above the prompt. Reset works and I close the terminal but when I reopen it, it's still there.

[image: screnshot]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Your screenshot didn't show and I'm unsure why you're seeing what you describe unless you modified your $PS1 (prompt:shell), `.bash_profile` or equivalent (.bashrc..) file. the `history` command will show your command history to review what you did (at terminal) but doesn't show what you did after loading an editor for example. You could `ls -ltrha ~` (directory, long, human, all files sorted with newest at end) see if  any .bash* files have recent dates and thus were edited by you, but I'm only guessing here.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did ls -ltrha ~  and I somehow did edit .bashrc . I have no clue how I did that but there at the end of that file was the line of text that wouldn't go away in my terminal. So, I edited it out, saved the file as it was and everything is back to normal. Thank you so much, that was really bothering me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure why you're seeing what you describe unless you modified your $PS1 (prompt:shell), `.bash_profile` or equivalent (`.bashrc` ..) file.

The `history` command will show your command history to review what you did (at terminal) but doesn't show what you did after loading an editor for example.

You could also `ls -ltrha ~` (directory, long, human, all files sorted with newest at end; ~ is a shorthand for your home [user] directory) see if any .bash* files have recent dates and thus were edited by you.  If you find the cause (text annoying you), just remove it.